# printing using document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>

<input id="t1" type="text">

<script type="text/javascript">

function myfunction() {
    var no=document.getElementById("t1").value;

    if(no==""||isNaN(no))
    {
        alert("Not Numeric");
    }
    else {
        for ( var int = 0; int < no; int++) {
            for ( var int2 = 0; int2 <=int; int2++) {
                document.write("*");
            }
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    }
}

</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()" >click me</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

The above code is showing output like this after entering the value: 5

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

But I am not getting the above output after I modified as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

<body>

<input id="t1" type="text">

<script>

function myfunction() {
    var no=document.getElementById("t1").value;

    if(no==""||isNaN(no))
    {
        alert("Not Numeric");
    }
    else {
        for ( var int = 0; int < no; int++) {
            for ( var int2 = 0; int2 <=int; int2++) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="*";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<br>";
        }
    }
}

</script>


<button type="button" onclick="myfunction()" >click me</button>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I just want the above output using inner html so that while showing output it will not display in another or new html page.

Comment: please remove unnecessary code.

Comment: use `+=` operator instead of `=` in `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you overwrite the contents of the `demo` element every time you use `innerHTML`.  For example,

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello ";    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "World";
```

outputs only "World".  To actually output "Hello World", you would have to concatenate the contents of the element with what's already there:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello ";    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "World";
```

or shortened:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "World";
```

However, accessing the DOM by using `document.getElementById("demo")` over and over again is very costly.  To avoid this, I would suggest you keep track of your output in a temporary variable and then output it into the DOM element at the end, as such:

```
function myfunction() {
    var no=document.getElementById("t1").value,
        output = "";

    if(no==""||isNaN(no))
    {
        alert("Not Numeric");
    }
    else {
        for ( var int = 0; int < no; int++) {
            for ( var int2 = 0; int2 <=int; int2++) {
                output+="*";
            }
            output+="<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `+=` instead of `=` to append to an elements innerHTML, else you're just overriding it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vf6hJ/1)

#### JavaScript

```
...
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="*";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="<br>";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` will append the text to the DOM. `innerHTML` sets the content of the given DOM element, so setting `innerHTML` will not append additional asterisks.

Instead:

```
for (var int = 0; int < no; int++) {
    for (var int2 = 0; int2 <=int; int2++) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="*";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="<br>";
}
```

In general, when you feel like using `document.write`, there is usually a better way. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Answer (score 0):

Below code is clearing off all the * that is created. Because innerHTML would replace complete contents of demo. Hence concatenate 
 with results got in for loop

```
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="<br>";
```

Comment: This is only partially correct... Even inside the loop, the OP's code is already overwriting the contents every time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected.  what you need to know is the [**difference and when to you `document.write` and `innerHTML`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085109/when-should-one-use-innerhtml-and-when-document-write-in-javascript)

**document.write:** writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.

**innerHTML:** property sets or returns the inner HTML of an element.

> **`innerHTML`** and **`document.write`** are not really comparable methods to
>   dynamically change/insert content, since their usage is different and
>   for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `innerHTML` will overwrite the entire inner HTML of your element each time. But why use `innerHTML` immediately? Just keep one string, query the DOM once, and be less wasteful:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="t1" type="text">

        <button type="button" id="button">Click me</button>

        <pre id="demo">A placeholder!</pre>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var size = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value, 10);

            if(!isNaN(size)) {
                var result = "";

                for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    for(var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                        result += "*";
                    }

                    result += "\n";
                }

                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```