# Typescript HTML display

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I am new to typescript.  I have a question of displaying html using typescript.  Below is my HTML code:

```html
<div itemprop="copy-paste-block">
  <ul>
    <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">ITS – signed support agreement</span></span>
      <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
        <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">27 parts received to date.</span></span>
        </li>
        <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">Working larger structures package.</span></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">GECAS </span></span>
      <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
        <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">Working full ship set structures package.</span></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">Skywest</span></span>
      <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
        <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">Price rationalization presented to mgmt.</span></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>United
      <ul style="list-style-type:circle;">
        <li><span style="font-size:11pt;"><span style="font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">Single Radome oppty.</span></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And when I use

```
document.write(htmlcontent);
```

It displays correct as show here:

[image: correct]

However, when I use

```
document.body.innerHTML = htmlcontent
```

The display was changed, missing some contents and changed some formats shown below
[image]

I wonder if this is what supposed to happen....and if there anything I should do to make body.innerHTML display correctly?  Thanks.

This link didn't answer my question:
[When should one use .innerHTML and when document.write in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085109/when-should-one-use-innerhtml-and-when-document-write-in-javascript)

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript. TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript before being used by the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to set the the `.innerHTML` of the whole document body. Instead, just select a `div` with `document.getElementById` and set the `.innerHTML` property on that.

Furthermore, don't use `document.write`. It's old and dangerous. Just don't touch it.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="root-element"></div>
  <script>
  document.getElementById("root-element").innerHTML = htmlcontent
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @HereticMonkey see my edit for an example on how to do it

Comment: @HereticMonkey whoops, I'm so used to only seeing them in code it didn't click that the text was wrong XD

Comment: No problem. I'm willing to forget it ever happened :).

Comment: Thank you both for the input.  but this didn't solve the issue: when it is using innerHTML, the little dot (bullet point) in front of each line disappeared....any thoughts?

Comment: @Heisenberg I'd need more information because this should still be showing those little circles. Are you using React or something like that?

Comment: @randomusername Thanks.  I think it part of other pre-built script inside Power BI....I was making a power bi custom visual to display html....I reported this to Microsoft and wait to see them deny and ignore this bug they have.